# Can you create a GET style URL if a website doesn't provide the option?

Tags: url, post, get, automation

I'd like to reach directly a certain view of a webpage which needs a couple of clicks. Is there a way to "create" a GET URL (i.e. site.com/demo_form.asp?name1=value1&name2=value2) if certain variables are not currently present?

Practical example: I'd like a direct URL to access the view that I get by clicking on http://techcrunch.com/search/crunchweek#stq=crunchweek&stp=1 then clicking on the left to "past week" and on the top on "LATEST".

Is there a URL for that?

thank you

Comment: Is there are URL for that where? If you are the developer why are you asking us?

Comment: "A way"? There are a gazillions of way. Do you need to script or to program this? Under with OS or language?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way of doing that.

In that case, it was a design flaw made by the site's developer.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your practical example: when you click on those links what the sites does is an AJAX request to retrieve some JSON data, parse them and display those in the view.
The full URL of this request is something like this:

```
https://api.swiftype.com/api/v1/public/engines/search.json?callback=jQuery111309158905502408743_1443789586149&q=crunchweek&engine_key=k9ZTjaGcF2KsrKSpBKzt&page=1&per_page=10&search_fields%5Bposts%5D%5B%5D=title%5E8&search_fields%5Bposts%5D%5B%5D=body%5E10&search_fields%5Bposts%5D%5B%5D=author%5E4&facets%5Bposts%5D%5B%5D=author_facets&facets%5Bposts%5D%5B%5D=category_facets&facets%5Bposts%5D%5B%5D=tag_facets&facets%5Bposts%5D%5B%5D=object_type&filters%5Bposts%5D%5Btimestamp%5D%5Btype%5D=range&sort_field%5Bposts%5D=timestamp&sort_direction%5Bposts%5D=desc&spelling=always&_=1443789586152
```

which gives back the data to display first 10 latest articels displayed in the frame you are looking for, in a form like this: `/**/jQuery111309158905502408743_1443789586149({"record_count":10,"records":{...}...`

You can fire this GET (or even a POST) with programs like `wget` or `curl`, or using web tools like JSON Webservice Tester or alike, or you can do it with many programming language in many ways. If you need to automate this, you need to know how the parameters in the above query are updated, how the session is being updated, and what security checks are performed on your get.
So you can do it, but first you need to know what you are really asking for.